# SQL DB2 Max Date Needed for Date Generated from Case

Tags: sql, date, db2, max

I have a query:

```
select nfdoco as lease ,NFEFTE as billingend  , NFSUDT  as bill_suspend_date, NFAG/100 as rent,
case
when NFSUDT  = 0  then NFEFTE 
else min(NFEFTE ,  NFSUDT )
end as BillEndDate

from proddta.f1502b

where NFGLC in ('MINR', 'MING')
```

I need to get the max BillEndDate for each nfdoco.  I have used a similar feature before with the dense rank, however that doesn't seem to be working, since the column i am trying to max is calculated.

Is this possible?  Does anyone have any suggestions on alternate routes?

Comment: Is this for SQL Server or DB2?

Comment: you could try to put your select inside another select, than u can adress BillEndDate as if it where a normal field. Someting like select max(t.billenddate)  from ( your select) t

Comment: I am creating DB2 views using SQL to connect to an AS400

Comment: GuidoG - I am a beginner, is there anyway you can explain a little more how I would do this?

Answer (score 1):

Not tested it, but on SQL Server this should work

```
select T.lease, T.billingend, T.NFSUD, T.RENT, max(T.BillEndDate)
from  (
    select nfdoco as lease ,
       NFEFTE as billingend  , 
       NFSUDT  as bill_suspend_date, 
       NFAG/100 as rent,
       case
          when NFSUDT  = 0  then NFEFTE 
          else min(NFEFTE ,  NFSUDT )
       end as BillEndDate
    from proddta.f1502b
    where NFGLC in ('MINR', 'MING')  
    ) T
group by T.lease, T.billingend, T.NFSUD, T.RENT
```

For your last comment change the query like this

```
select T.lease, T.RENT, max(T.BillEndDate)
from  (
    select nfdoco as lease ,
       NFEFTE as billingend  , 
       NFSUDT  as bill_suspend_date, 
       NFAG/100 as rent,
       case
          when NFSUDT  = 0  then NFEFTE 
          else min(NFEFTE ,  NFSUDT )
       end as BillEndDate
    from proddta.f1502b
    where NFGLC in ('MINR', 'MING')  
    ) T
group by T.lease, T.Rent
```

Comment: thanks so much!  I don't have it 100% yet - there are a few changes, but I am definitely on the right track now!

Comment: it the answer helps, consider an accept or an upvote

Comment: The only thing is, Guido - this query does work (in that it doesn't generate errors), but I need to get the rent for the max(BillEndDate) for each Lease.  I am still getting multiple lines for each lease.  I'm not sure how to sort this out.  I will be happy to accept the answer, once it is complete - just to ensure it is most beneficial for other users.  Like I said, I'm new at this. Thanks!

Comment: if u want the max(billenddate) per lease, than u will have to restrict your fields to lease and max(billenddate)  select T.Lease, max(T.BillEndDate) from ( query ) T group by T.Lease

Comment: sorry, this doesn't work.  it isn't eliminating anything.  I will try something, and get back to you.  I think the max is in the wrong spot or something.

Comment: Guido.... I feel like we are getitng very close.  I just need the rent that goes with the max(BillEndDate).  I tried just grouping by Lease, but that doesn't seem to work either.